# I2C High Speed Multiple Slaves Layout

Tags: i2c

I am working on a system where I need to have 16 I2C devices on one bus. Due to data rates I need to run at 3.4 Mbit high speed mode. Are there any design/layout guidelines to help deal with a large number of slaves on a high-speed I2C bus? I am worried about reflections/stubs corrupting the signal too much as I've never used high-speed mode.

Comment: What device is driving this I2C bus? The datasheets for that device should give you many answers.

Comment: Before you worry about reflections and stubs, what's the total capacitance loading the bus, and can your devices drive a strong enough pull-up to switch this capacitance at 3.4 MHz?